# How to indent output of git-clone

Tags: bash, git, sed

I've been trying to indent the output of git clone. I tried using sed but it isn't working... here's what I've tried so far.

```
git clone https://github.com/test/HelloWorld --progress | sed 's/^/  /g'
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does indent the output mean?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git outputs to both stdout and stderr. To filter both you can use `|&` or `2&1 |`.

It also prints progress lines that are updated in place with `\r` carriage returns. You could use a regex to also indent those lines in addition to the normal ones. I would also use `-u` for unbuffered input and output.

```
git clone https://github.com/test/HelloWorld --progress |&
    sed -ur 's/(^|\r)/\1  /g'
```

Note that `sed` is line-based and only prints output when it hits a `\n` newline. Lines separated with `\r` carriage returns could be buffered up for a while before being printed.

Answer (score 0):

Once I found `pr`:

```
git clone https://github.com/test/HelloWorld --progress 2>&1 | pr -tro 3
```